# Why is my dispatch not performing the console.log?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

SO im having a hard time understanding reducers and dispatch, and useSelectors.

In this example, im clicking a button via onRowItemClick. This should in theory, dispatch an action, which is playAudio.

That action is inside a reducer? And i would imagine it should console.log an empty array, which is the current state. However, when i click it, nothing happens in the console.

Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialState = [];

    const AudioSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'AudioSlice',
        initialState,
        reducers: {
            playAudio(state){
                console.log(current(state));
            }
        },
     });

export const { playAudio} = AudioSlice.actions;

export default AudioSlice.reducer;
```

The dispatch:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { playAudio } from 'slices/AudioSlice';

const ProjectPageAudioTab = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onRowItemClick = () => {
        dispatch(playAudio());
    };
}
export default ProjectPageAudioTab;
```

Comment: You are defining the `onRowItemClick` function but you never use it, why would you expect it to ever be called? You should assign it to the `onClick` of some DOM element.

Comment: Lets assume it works. If i replace dispatch in my code with just console.log, it works.

Comment: Is the slice reducer actually added to the store setup in `configureStore`?

Comment: Hey Josh where do you get current from ?

Comment: @markerikson, yeah thats what i thought the problem was late last night. I have added it to the store, still nothing. ive tried just console.logging a string too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give an answer at this point without seeing the rest of the code.  If you can put up the code as a CodeSandbox or a repo I might be able to look further.

Comment: I've created a CodeSandbox based on your question. Seems to work ok and log to the console: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-sk56il?file=/src/ProjectPageAudioTab.tsx

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Turns out the code i was working on had previously used redux, and left the store. So none of my dispatches or selectors were working because they were targeting a different store. I managed to check the state via redux tools in chrome, and thats how i saw it was reading state from the previous store, and not mine.